# split based on the last dot and create a new column with the last part of the string

Tags: awk, split, tabs

I have a file with 2 columns. In the first column, there are several strings (IDs) and in the second values. In the strings, there are a number of dots that can be variable. I would like to split these strings based on the last dot. I found in the forum how remove the last past after the last dot, but I don't want to remove it. I would like to create a new column with the last part of the strings, using bash command (e.g. awk)

Example of strings:

```
   5_8S_A.3-C_1.A   50
   6_FS_B.L.3-O_1.A 20 
   H.YU-201.D   80
   UI-LP.56.2011.A  10
```

Example of output:

```
   5_8S_A.3-C_1 A   50
   6_FS_B.L.3-O_1   A   20 
   H.YU-201 D   80
   UI-LP.56.2011    A   10
```

I tried to solve it by using the following command but it works if I have just 1 dot in the string:

```
awk -F' ' '{{split($1, arr, "."); print arr[1] "\t" arr[2] "\t" $2}}' file.txt
```

Comment: yes, sure.. I tried to solve it by using the following command but it works if I have just 1 dot in the string:

awk -F' ' ' {{split($1, arr, "."); print arr[1]  "\t" arr[2] "\t"  $2}}' file.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this `sed`:

```sh
sed -E 's/^([[:blank:]]*[^[:blank:]]+)\.([^[:blank:]]+)/\1 \2/' file

   5_8S_A.3-C_1 A   50
   6_FS_B.L.3-O_1 A 20
   H.YU-201 D   80
   UI-LP.56.2011 A  10
```

**Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `([[:blank:]]*[^[:blank:]]+)`: Capture group #2 to match 0 or more whitespaces followed by 1+ non-whitespace characters.
- `\.`: Match a dot. Since this regex pattern is **greedy** it will match until last dot
- `([^[:blank:]]+)`: Capture group #2 to match 1+ non-whitespace characters
- `\1 \2`: Replacement to place a space between capture value #1 and capture value #2

Answer (score 2):

Assumptions:

- each line consists of two (white) space delimited fields
- first field contains at least one period (`.`)

Sticking with OP's desire (?) to use `awk`:

```
awk '
{ n=split($1,arr,".")            # split first field on period (".")
  pfx=""
  for (i=1;i<n;i++) {            # print all but the nth array entry
      printf "%s%s",pfx,arr[i]
      pfx="."}
  print "\t" arr[n] "\t" $2}     # print last array entry and last field of line
' file.txt
```

Removing comments and reducing to a one-liner:

```
awk '{n=split($1,arr,"."); pfx=""; for (i=1;i<n;i++) {printf "%s%s",pfx,arr[i]; pfx="."}; print "\t" arr[n] "\t" $2}' file.txt
```

This generates:

```
5_8S_A.3-C_1    A       50
6_FS_B.L.3-O_1  A       20
H.YU-201        D       80
UI-LP.56.2011   A       10
```

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples, here is one more variant of `rev` + `awk` solution.

```
rev Input_file | awk '{sub(/\./,OFS)} 1' | rev
```

***Explanation:*** Simple explanation would be, using `rev` to print reverse order(from last character to first character) for each line, then sending its output as a standard input to `awk` program where substituting first dot(which is last dot as per OP's shown samples only) with spaces and printing all lines. Then sending this output as a standard input to `rev` again to print output into correct order(to remove effect of 1st rev command here).

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sed 's/\.\([^.]*$\)/\t\1/' file
5_8S_A.3-C_1    A       50
6_FS_B.L.3-O_1  A       20
H.YU-201        D       80
UI-LP.56.2011   A       10
```

Comment: Works for given example data but if there is `50.8` as last value in first line then it may not work.

Comment: Agreed but that doesn't seem to be the case given the OPs sample input .